# find the open interval or intervals in which the given function is continuous

Tags: functions, continuity

I need to find the open interval or intervals in which the given function is continuous.

The function is

$f(x) = \frac{1}{x+2}$

How do I find that?

Thank you

Comment: Try to find the places where $f(x)$ is *not* continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+2}$ has a discontinuity at $x=-2$ (a vertical asymptote). Therefore, the function is continuous on the interval: $$(-\infty,-2) \; \cup \; (-2,\infty).$$

Comment: What about $x^{1/4}$ Is it continuous in R?

Comment: It is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

The map $f$ cannot assign to $-2$ any real number and hence is not defined at $-2$. The map $f$ can assign to every $x \neq -2$ the number $\frac{1}{x+2}$; we claim that $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{ -2 \}$.
But $f$ is the composition 
$$x \mapsto x+2 =: y \mapsto y^{-1} = \frac{1}{x+2},$$
and both the transition maps are continuous suitably everywhere; hence $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{2\}$.

Comment: What about $x^{1/4}$ Is it continuous in R?

Comment: @zeeks Note that what I said was "... are continuous **suitably** everywhere". The map $x \mapsto x^{1/4}$ is not even defined for $x < 0$. :)

Answer (score 1):

Any function in the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are both polynomials is called a rational function (a term I'm sure you're familiar with). To test the continuity of a rational function, look at the denominator. Whenever the denominator is $0$, then your function becomes a term divided by $0$, which is undefined. Whenever a function is undefined, it is discontinuous.

In this case, set your denominator $x=2$ equal to $0$. Clearly the solution is $x=-2$. Since this is the case, the function is discontinuous at $x=-2$. Thus, the intervals of continuity of the function is basically any real number other than $-2$. Consequently, in interval notation,

$$(-\infty,-2) \;\cup\; (-2,\infty)$$

Satisfies the function's continuity.

I hope this helps!

Comment: What about $x^{1/4}$ Is it continuous in R?